# New to app development. Creating a button that links one class to another?

Tags: android, helper

I have created two classes. I want to have a button on class 1 (MainActivity) that when it is pressed, it will take me to class 2 (Alphabet). I have tried numerous ways of doing it and I have been unsuccessful. Here is my original code below. Can anyone help me?
Sorry, I am new to app developing.

```
package com.example.lullabymain;


import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;




public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private MediaPlayer mp;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // new code

        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button5).setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        int resId = 0;
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1: resId = R.raw.rockabye; break;
        case R.id.button2: resId = R.raw.hushlittlebaby; break;
        case R.id.button3: resId = R.raw.twinkle; break;
        case R.id.button4: resId = R.raw.hickory; break;
        case R.id.button5: resId = R.raw.oldmcd; break;


        }
        //release any resources from previous mediaplayer
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.release();
        }
        //create a new mediaplayer to play this sound
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
        mp.start();

    }


    @Override
    protected void  onStop()
    {
        //stop audio
        super.onStop();
        mp.stop();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The code below is the code that I attempted which includes 'Intent'

```
package com.example.lullabymain;

import android.os.Bundle; 

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.media.AudioManager;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private MediaPlayer mp;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // new code
        **View button6 = findViewById(R.id.button6);
        button6.setOnClickListener(this);**       
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button5).setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        int resId = 0;
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1: resId = R.raw.rockabye; break;
        case R.id.button2: resId = R.raw.hushlittlebaby; break;
        case R.id.button3: resId = R.raw.twinkle; break;
        case R.id.button4: resId = R.raw.hickory; break;
        case R.id.button5: resId = R.raw.oldmcd; break;
        **case R.id.button6:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Alphabet.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;**

        }
        //release any resources from previous mediaplayer
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.release();
        }
        //create a new mediaplayer to play this sound
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
        mp.start();

    }


    @Override
    protected void  onStop()
    {
        //stop audio
        super.onStop();
        mp.stop();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Alphabet an Activity, is this added in your manifest?

Comment: How and where do I add it to my manifest? @RvdK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in MainActivity Activity you are not adding setOnClickListener to button6 but in onClick method you are trying to start Activity on button6 click . to get your code working add `setOnClickListener` to button6 also as

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private MediaPlayer mp;
Button button6 ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // new code
    button6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    button6.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and register Alphabet Activity in Manifest as :

```
<activity android:name=".Alphabet" />
```

Comment: It is there in his code, View button6 = findViewById(R.id.button6);
 button6.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: @imran kahn I have got a setOnClickListenr(this); already there?

Comment: is there something I can add for it to work @RvdK would have assumed creating a button to link to another class would be a simple thing?

Comment: @imrankhan I just tried your code and it didn't work? Sorry for sounding stupid. Just struggling here

Comment: @user1879688 : you are getting any exception on button click?

Comment: every time i write this code, it states that button should be imported and written as import android.widget.Button; when this is done and played on the adk then the button is pressed, the app closes @imrankhan

Comment: sorry for sounding so stupid @imrankhan but where do I register <activity android:name=".Alphabet" />
 under the res file? or my xml file?

Comment: not a problem post your AndroidManifest.xml file then i will edit it for u

Comment: or search for `<activity ...` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` and put `<activity android:name=".Alphabet" />` line before it

Comment: Im struggling to send it altogether so I had to post it on this.. @prosperK

Comment: <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
            android:name=".Alphabet" />"
            <intent-filter>

Comment: thats how ive done it and the error says

error: Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute

Comment: see my edit answer and change your `AndroidManifest.xml `as in my answer

Comment: Now its not working. it states error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) under         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

Comment: This is my entire manifest

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lullabymain"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".Alphabet" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

This is so frustrating :(

Comment: Just tried your code, when clicking on the button while running on the adk, the application crashes @prosperk around 20 errors appear

Comment: means we are near to solve it can u plz post logcat when application is crashing?

Comment: 12-05 18:44:20.163: E/AndroidRuntime(827): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
12-05 18:44:20.163: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1013)

Comment: k comment these lines and try to run your app mp = `MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
        mp.start();`

Comment: this might sound incredibly stupid. but how do i know which part to comment out..

Comment: these lines mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId); mp.start();

Comment: Okay so now i've done that, obviously the audio isn't working. However it goes on to my second class, Alphabet. But as soon as it goes on to the class, the app closes down application crashes as on the adk

Comment: what u have doing inside Alphabet class?

Comment: trying to play audio files as I am in the first class

Comment: do you think there is a way of playing audion on my first class, have a button which would link my second class and then have audio on my second class too?

Comment: yes for this you will need to post another question because this is new issue and if this answer help u then u can accept it as answer .Thanks so much and post new question then i will try to help u

Comment: No, thank you. Hopefully now I can connect by two classes up without it crashing and playing the media

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do custom coding, you need to learn langauges like Objective-C or Swift to develop iOS app. Or another way is mobile app development platform. With the help of app development tools you can develop apps with drag & Drop facilities without writing a single line of code.

I am an iOS app developer, I have tried most of the mobile app development platforms.  I have developed more than 50 apps till today with the help of Phonegap, Telerik, Configure.IT etc. They are running successfully on app store.

As per my experience in this field, I recommend developers as well as beginners to use mobile app development platform like http://www.configure.it/, because it provides automatic coding, app preview facility, direct API connect and a lot more features. These things save a lot more development time and provides fast and well designed app in much less time.

The main benefit of this tool, it is web based platform so you do not require to buy Mac system, you can make an app from any place as well as from any system.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the context of {this} you are using the {this} of the onClickListener. use getApplicationContext();

```
Button button6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Alphabet.class));
    }
});
```

What are the errors that your code is throwing?

Comment: tried your code. it asked to have a import android.widget.Button; which i did do. then when it was running on the adk, i clicked on the button, the app was closed due to some 'unfortunate error'

Comment: Unfortunate Error? I have never seen such a thing... did that come from LogCat? Or a compile error? However I did forget to close the function properly, so see my edit, and see if that fixes anything. If a problem still arises, try and in Eclipse click: Project -> Clean

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.lullabymain;

import android.os.Bundle; 

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.media.AudioManager;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private MediaPlayer mp;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // new code
    Button button6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    button6.setOnClickListener(this);      
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button5).setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void onClick(View v) {
    int resId = 0;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1: resId = R.raw.rockabye; break;
    case R.id.button2: resId = R.raw.hushlittlebaby; break;
    case R.id.button3: resId = R.raw.twinkle; break;
    case R.id.button4: resId = R.raw.hickory; break;
    case R.id.button5: resId = R.raw.oldmcd; break;
    case R.id.button6:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.example.lullabymain.Alphabet.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    }
    //release any resources from previous mediaplayer
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.release();
    }
    //create a new mediaplayer to play this sound
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
    mp.start();

}


@Override
protected void  onStop()
{
    //stop audio
    super.onStop();
    mp.stop();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: I tried your exact code and it requested me to import android.widget.Button; as Button button6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6); would come up with a error otherwise @viks

Comment: Just add import android.widget.Button; after import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set on click listeners on the required buttons 
and followed by Intents to go to your new class for example 
        Intent i5 = new Intent(this, HadithList.class);
            startActivity(i5);

Comment: You are just sick. How do you do it? Thanks